# How can update a column based on the value of another column in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

Basically I have Product table like this:

```
date       price
---------  -----
02-SEP-14     50  
03-SEP-14     60  
04-SEP-14     60  
05-SEP-14     60  
07-SEP-14     71  
08-SEP-14     45  
09-SEP-14     45  
10-SEP-14     24  
11-SEP-14     60
```

**I need to update the table in this form**

```
date       price   id
---------  -----   --
02-SEP-14     50    1
03-SEP-14     60    2
04-SEP-14     60    2
05-SEP-14     60    2
07-SEP-14     71    3
08-SEP-14     45    4
09-SEP-14     45    4
10-SEP-14     24    5
11-SEP-14     60    6
```

**What I have tried:**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE user_id_seq
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  CACHE 20;

ALTER TABLE Product
  ADD (ID number);

UPDATE Product SET ID = user_id_seq.nextval;
```

This is updating the ID in the usual way like 1,2,3,4,5..

I have no idea how to do it using basic SQL commands. Please suggest how can I make it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where did the first price (50) come from? It's in the desired result but not in the inputs. Then: do you assign a new number if the new price is different from the immediately preceding one? Or only if it is new for the entire sequence? So, for example, say 11-SEP-14 has price 60. Do you assign the number 6, or do you assign the number 2?

Comment: Also: Do you really want to STORE this data, or is it better to create a view where the column is calculated dynamically? If you store it in your base table, what are you going to do when you need to change the base data (for example, you make a correction to the 04-SEP-14 price, updating it from 60 to 55)?

Comment: I just edited the question. I hope now it is quite better to understand.

Comment: I asked a very simple question, is it not understandable? Suppose you add one more row, `11-SEP-14  60`. What number do you assign to this row, the number 6 (next in sequence, because the price has changed), or the number 2 (because the price 60 exists in the list already, even though it is not the most recent price)?

Comment: It should be 6, as far as it's not coming under consecutive months. Good question.. Sorry I didn't notice at first..

Comment: Another thing I will definitely use a view for practical use. But for learning purpose using table is OK I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to create a view from your base data. I assume you have more than one product (identified by product id), and that the price dates aren't necessarily consecutive. The sequence is separate for each product id. (Also, `product` should be the name of a different table - where the product id is primary key, and you have other information such as product name, category, etc. The table in your post would be more properly called something like `price_history`.)

```
alter session set nls_date_format='dd-MON-rr';

create table product ( prod_id number, dt date, price number );

insert into product ( prod_id, dt, price )
  select 101, '02-SEP-14', 50 from dual union all 
  select 101, '03-SEP-14', 60 from dual union all  
  select 101, '04-SEP-14', 60 from dual union all 
  select 101, '05-SEP-14', 60 from dual union all 
  select 101, '07-SEP-14', 71 from dual union all  
  select 101, '08-SEP-14', 45 from dual union all 
  select 101, '09-SEP-14', 45 from dual union all 
  select 101, '10-SEP-14', 24 from dual union all 
  select 101, '11-SEP-14', 60 from dual union all
  select 102, '02-SEP-14', 45 from dual union all
  select 102, '04-SEP-14', 45 from dual union all
  select 102, '05-SEP-14', 60 from dual union all
  select 102, '06-SEP-14', 50 from dual union all
  select 102, '09-SEP-14', 60 from dual
;

commit;

create view product_vw ( prod_id, dt, price, seq ) as
  select prod_id, dt, price, 
         count(flag) over (partition by prod_id order by dt)
  from   ( select prod_id, dt, price,
                  case when price = lag(price) over (partition by prod_id order by dt)
                       then null else 1 end as flag
           from   product
         )
;
```

Now check what the view looks like:

```
select * from product_vw;

PROD_ID DT                       PRICE        SEQ
------- ------------------- ---------- ----------
    101 02/09/0014 00:00:00         50          1
    101 03/09/0014 00:00:00         60          2
    101 04/09/0014 00:00:00         60          2
    101 05/09/0014 00:00:00         60          2
    101 07/09/0014 00:00:00         71          3
    101 08/09/0014 00:00:00         45          4
    101 09/09/0014 00:00:00         45          4
    101 10/09/0014 00:00:00         24          5
    101 11/09/0014 00:00:00         60          6
    102 02/09/0014 00:00:00         45          1
    102 04/09/0014 00:00:00         45          1
    102 05/09/0014 00:00:00         60          2
    102 06/09/0014 00:00:00         50          3
    102 09/09/0014 00:00:00         60          4
```

Comment: Is it possible without PROD_ID? It won't be feasible to add extra column in the table. When I am using view I expect that my table is not changed.

Comment: @SOUBHIKRAKSHIT - do you mean you have one product only? Then remove `partition by prod_id` everywhere, and remove all other occurrences of `prod_id`; no other changes should be needed.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE:  This answers the question that was originally asked.  The OP changed the data.

If your data is not too large, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
update product p
    set id = (select count(distinct p2.price)
              from product p2
              where p2.date <= p.date
             );
```

If your data is larger, then `merge` is more appropriate.

Comment: This will not produce the result desired by the OP. The same price is assigned the same sequential number only over consecutive dates; it gets a different seq number if there are intervening days with different prices. The original post wasn't clear about that; that's what follow-up questions are for.

Comment: Yes.. This query will not produce the desired output. Will you please give the solution if the data is larger?

Comment: @mathguy . . . The OP changed the data.  This answers the original question (you can look at the edit history).  I added a note to that effect.

Comment: I saw the original post. I asked for *clarification* - because the data wasn't sufficient to cover that case. The OP changed the data after he answered my question. My point was that your solution answered a question that was *ambiguous* precisely for this reason. Perhaps you didn't think about this other possibility, which is OK. I was pointing out that asking a few questions upfront would avoid misinterpreting the question (even if it's the OP's fault for not being crystal clear).

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cts AS  
(
SELECT row_number() over (partition by price order by price ) as id
,date
,price  
FROM Product 
)
UPDATE p
set p.id = cts.id 
from product p join cts on cts.id = p.id
```

Comment: This is invalid for Oracle

Answer (score -1):

This is the best way by which you try to do.
There is no another simple way to do this using simple statements